# Red dots in the Review Queues dropdown?

Tags: support, review-queues

I don't mean the red dot that's sometimes superimposed on the "Review Queues" icon (I kinda know what that one means).

I mean the round "bullet-points" against individual review queues, that used to be gray, and indicated that there are items available in the queue. As of today, these dots are dark red instead. Just wondered whether this is a site design change, or some error on my part?